# why is embedding JSON in XML bad?

Tags: xml, json, language-agnostic, format

My gut tells me that putting one format in another is wrong, but I can't seem to come up with concrete reasons.

```
<root>
 <stuff>
  thing
 </stuff>
 <more>
  <[!CDATA[{"a":["b","c"]}]]>
 </more>
</root>
```

versus just putting it in the xml

```
<root>
 <stuff>
  thing
 </stuff>
 <more>
  <a>
   b
  </a>
  <a>
   c
  </a>
 </more>
</root>
```

The two sections are logically going to be parsed by different code, but as an interchange format, is it ok to mix and match syntax?

Does your answer change if we have an existing endpoint that parses the JSON response? We would have to recode this endpoint for XML ingestion.

Comment: Why is storing sqlite files as blobs in databases bad?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As an interchange format using two formats puts extra burden on people who want to inter-operate with you. Now they need to have an XML parser *and* a JSON parser.

It also makes it harder for people to grok the format, as they have to mentally switch gears when thinking about different parts of your file.

Finally, you won't be able to easily do things that look at the entire structure at once. For example, you can't use XPath to grab JSON bits, nor can you treat the entire response as a JavaScript object. By mixing two formats you get a "worst of both worlds" problem when it comes to manipulating the data.

Comment: Does your answer change if we have an existing endpoint that parses the JSON response? We would have to recode this endpoint for XML ingestion.

Comment: Since you already have a solution - ie; a JSON parser on top of an XML parser - then the answers to your question will be in respect to portability, readability, maintainability, and plain old fashioned taste. Sure it works *now*, but think of who might read it in the future, who you might pass the XML to, how you will explain to them why they need a JSON parser at the end of it, and so on. It does rather seem like you're putting off work for now that may result in much more work being created later.

Comment: @Paul: If it works for your current implementation there's no reason to change it right now. However if you start coming up with creative (read: stinky) ways of getting around the issues Laurence described that's when you want to stick with one or the other.

Answer (score 9):

It's sorta like the database normalization debate. It's cleaner and more elegant to do everything in pure XML (or normalize your database schema), that way you're not unnecessarily coupled to your particular implementation. But if you have to then convert the XML to JavaScript objects (or join 5 tables for every damned `SELECT`), you may end up writing lots of extra code and incur unnecessary performance hits.

It all depends on how you balance convenience with formal correctness. If this is an XML interchange format that will be standardized by the W3C and used by millions then dear God, do not use JSON. If this is for an in-house app that'll only be processed by code you yourself have written then screw it, just throw the JSON in there and move on!

Comment: +1. good practices are good. but they cannot replace good thinking. sometimes know patterns are not the best solution to a problem. sometimes a hack is the right thing. anything you do, know WHY you do it, and the more messy it is, the more you need to document it, and to encapsulate the messyness somewhere, so you can easily replace it some day ... :)

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion XML is the prefered Data transfer representation, but JSON is far more expressive when it comes to Maps and Arrays.   I would have no issue with embedding JSON into xml to represent a list or map.

Answer (score 2):

First, I realize that I'm posting 8 years after this question was asked, but I promise I believe I have a valid reason to do so.

I agree with all of the reasons that this is wrong, but there are always boundary cases that come up. For example, I'm working with some legacy applications that have some requirements:

1. Communication with the external system MUST use SOAP.
2. The SOAP communication MUST be described by a WSDL file.
3. Our system must ingest AND COMPILE the WSDL file for use, which generates a bunch of compiled Java classes and methods.
4. If the WSDL is updated, our system must re-compile the WSDL, which requires following the FULL change process, which can take months.
5. "Their system" that needs to ingest the SOAP data from us is being developed and maintained by a completely separate team, and there are various barriers prohibiting the two teams from actually collaborating. (Basically, we have one chance to throw something over the wall that they can use and extend as necessary; any back-and-forth will delay the project by months).
6. None of the above factors can be changed or questioned.

Taking all of those factors into consideration, I've decided that JSON inside of XML is the absolute best way forward for THIS particular problem. This allows us to still have meaningful parameters in our data, while avoiding any future changes in the WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

It's not inherently wrong. If you have a reason for doing it, and the alternatives are worse, then you should do it. As **always** a solution needs to be judged in the context it runs in (academics be damned).

In my case I have a global database that has a RESTful JSON API, an EU regulation that says I **have to** create a local copy from which the data can be accessed if the global database is unreachable and an infrastructure built on SOAP and XML.

We only need five fields from the hundred field JSON record for day-to-day operations. So no, I'm not going to pretend that purism leads to good solutions and introduce a completely new standard to our API infrastructure. I'm going to extract the few fields I need and return the rest as JSON wrapped inside a CDATA section.

Of course, our client applications don't use XML parsers so this doesn't require them to use two parsers. They use SOAP frameworks that do the parsing for them.